# Ruby on Rails resque task gets error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, resque, resque-scheduler

I'm trying to use resque in my ruby on rails application.

I created resque.rake file in lib/tasks folder

```
require 'resque/tasks'

task 'resque:setup' => :environment
```

I've started redis server by following line

```
redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf
```

I have this RakeFile in my application:

```
require_relative 'config/application'

Rails.application.load_tasks
```

But when I run the following command to start rake

```
rake resque:work QUEUE='*'
```

I'm getting this error:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- resque/tasks
```

I can't see What I'm missing,

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Note: I'm using rails 5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

In rails you can add this in your `config/application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Don't worry this is really easy to miss in the Rails doc's. It's just a small mention on this page

Go to this page and search for "config.autoload_paths" if you'd like to read more about it.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths

Also depending on how you build the app (with or without documentation) you may see comments about this in the application.rb

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  # Add additional load paths for your own custom dirs
  # config.load_paths += %W( #{RAILS_ROOT}/extras )
  config.load_paths << "#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/models/some_model_group"
  config.load_paths << "#{RAILS_ROOT}/lib"
end
```